# Connect RDS from a local aws sam instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I would like to use aws sam to setup my serverless application. I have used it with dynamoDB before. This was very easy to since all I had to do was setup a dynamoDB table as a resource and then link it to the lambda functions. AWS SAM  seams to know where the table is located. I was even able ot run the functions on my local machine using the sam-cli.
With RDS its a lot harder. The RDS Aurora Instance I am using sits behind a specific endpoint, in a specific subnet with security groups in my vpc protected by specific roles.
Now from what I understand, its aws sams job to use my template.yml to generate the roles and organize access rules for me.
But I don't think RDS is supported by aws sam by default, which means I would either be unable to test locally or need a vpn access to the aws vpc, which I am not a massive fan of, since it might be a real security risk.
I know RDS proxies exist, which can be created in aws sam, but they would also need vpc access, and so they just kick the problem down the road.
So how can I connect my aws sam project to RDS and if possible, execute the lambda functions on my machine?

Comment: For local testing I would recommend using a local Postgresql or MySQL database instead of connecting to the RDS instance.

Comment: I would have to deploy it at some point anyway, so how can I make sure it can connect to RDS once I deploy?

Comment: The would require the Lambda function to be deployed in the VPC with the RDS instance, and the RDS instance's security group to allow inbound access from the Lambda fucntion's security group. That's not something you can test locally.

Comment: then why does it work with dynamoDB, which is also deployed to a vpc?

Comment: No, you can't deploy DynamoDB to a VPC. DynamoDB is accessed via the AWS API, which uses IAM roles for access control. RDS is deployed in a VPC an uses security groups + username/password for access control.

Comment: since RDS proxy uses aws sam, would that make it possible to access the RDS from within a deployed lambda? Or would I still need to deploy to a preconfigured vpc? Because I would really to stick with the sam system even when using RDS

Comment: You can stick with the SAM system for all of this. SAM is an extension of CloudFormation, and as I understand you can use the full CloudFormation features if you want. I don't know what you mean by "RDS proxy uses aws sam" but I think you mean it is supported by AWS SAM. Either using RDS proxy or RDS serverless with the RDS data API would be something to look into.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225483/discussion-between-user2741831-and-mark-b).